# promise delay in mocha

Tags: promise, mocha.js, bluebird, sinon

I am learning sinon currently. My codes:

```
const bluebird = require('bluebird');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sinonTest = require('sinon-test')(sinon);

sinon.test = sinonTest;

describe('xxx', function _test() {
  this.timeout(2000);
  it('should', sinon.test(function() {
    return new bluebird.Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        console.log('123');
        resolve();
      } catch ( err ) {
        reject(err);
      };      
    })
    .then( () => console.log('456') )
    .delay(100)
    .then( () => console.log('789') )
    .then(function() {
    })
  }));
});
```

output:

```
xxx
    123
    456
```

Why the above code times out and stuck in `delay`? Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
const bluebird = require('bluebird');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sinonTest = require('sinon-test')(sinon);

sinon.test = sinonTest;

describe('xxx', function _test() {
  this.timeout(2000);
  it('should', sinon.test(function() {
    return bluebird
    .delay(100)
    .then( () => console.log('789') );
  }));
});
```

Output:

```
 Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks @Louis. Setting `useFakeTimers` works fine.

But I am just confused. Why in my project, there are no problems with the existing tests where `useFakeTimers` set to true by default? If `useFakeTimers` set true, promise delay cannot be used in `sinonTest()`?

By the way, I had this problem when upgrading `sinon` from `1.17.6` to `2.4.1`.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the sandboxes that Sinon creates have their configuration set so that the sandbox configuration option `useFakeTimers` is `true`. (Search for `defaultConfig` in this [documentation page](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.3.5/sandbox/).)

This means that while the sandbox is in effect, the clock appears to be stopped, and Bluebird's `delay` never resolves. You tell `sinon-test` to create sandboxes without fake timers by passing a 2nd parameter when you configure it. This 2nd parameter is actually a configuration object for Sinon sandboxes:

```
const sinonTest = require('sinon-test')(sinon,
                                        { useFakeTimers: false });
```

I have not tried it, but from eyeballing the code, it looks like you could use multiple configurations at the same time if you need some tests to use fake timers and some to not use fake timers:

```
const sinonTest = require('sinon-test');
const wrapper = sinonTest(sinon, { useFakeTimers: false });
const wrapperWithTimers = sinonTest(sinon);
```

You just need to use the right wrapper for the needs of the test.

---

You added the question:

> But I am just confused. Why in my project, there are no problems with the existing tests where `useFakeTimers` set to true by default? If `useFakeTimers` set true, promise delay cannot be used in `sinonTest()`?

By default `useFakeTimers` is `true`, but that won't cause a problem unless you have code that *depends* on the clock moving forward to work properly. I have many test suites where I use sandboxes and where I did not take care to turn off the fake timers and they work fine. Fake timers do not *generally* prevent asynchronous functions from running. If you do [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) while the sandbox is in effect, for instance, it should work just fine. It just affects functions that depend on the clock, like `setTimeout`, `setInterval` and `Date`.

Bluebird's `delay` method is affected because it [calls `setTimeout`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/e9406d915d88ab5bc912b06bc98da894240bc618/src/timers.js#L26).

Comment: if `{ useFakeTimers: false }` set, `delay` will not work?

Comment: I take the code in your question, plop it in a new file, edit to add the 2nd parameter `{ useFakeTimers: false }`, install the required packages and run Mocha and it work. I get all the `console.log` outputs and there is no time out. It worked when I did it before writing my answer and it works now. You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: yes. it is working now. You solved several questions of mine. Thanks. But I am just confused. Why in my project, there are no problems with the existing tests where `useFakeTimers` not set?

Comment: @BAE I had answered your last question in comments but I removed the comments and edited my answer to add the information there.

Comment: so, `delay` cannot be used inside `it()`, but can be used insize `before()` and `after()`? I used a lots of `delay` in my previous tests where `useFakeTimers` set to true.

Comment: It seems that I only used `delay` in `after` and `before`. not sure

Comment: @BAE The code that runs in the `before/beforeEach` hooks runs before the sandbox that is established by your call to `sinon.test` and the code that runs in the `after/afterEach` hooks runs after the sandbox is destroyed. So it is not affected by the sandbox you create for the test.

Comment: so, `useFakeTimers` only affect `it()`, not `before()`?